# DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg super().__init__(

Tags: python, ios, appium

```
import pytest
from appium import webdriver
class Test:

    def setup_class(self):
        print("setup from here")
        desired_caps = dict()
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'ios'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '12.1'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 8'
        desired_caps['app'] = 'com.masilotti.UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

> PycharmProjects/DemoTest/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py:274:
> DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please
> pass in an Options object with options kwarg
> super().**init**(

How to get rid of this warning, this warning appears whenever Unitest or Pytest are used.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You can't. (You could suppress it)

**Long answer:**

Selenium Webdriver now uses Options to pass capabilities, but the `appium python-client` which I'm assuming you are using does not yet support it. There is an issue open on the official repo [here](https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/640). And [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/64447d4b03f6986337d1ca8d8b6476653570bcc1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromium/options.py) is the implementation on the selenium side.

Here is the thread with the sollution: https://bytemeta.vip/repo/appium/python-client/issues/680

Add the following to the pytest.ini to supress the warning.

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = 
    # Appium team is aware of deprecation warning - https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/680
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

Or using python:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
            self.driver = webdriver.Remote(hub_url, caps)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those currently addressing this matter, in Selenium version 4 (which is also utilized by Appium), the configuration of desired capabilities has undergone a modification, and it is now recommended to employ the Options object.

Example in python for ios device:

```
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.ios.xcuitest.base import XCUITestOptions
desired_capabilities = {
'platformName': 'iOS',
'platformVersion': '16.4',
'deviceName': 'iPhone 12 Pro',
'automationName': 'XCUITest',
}
options = XCUITestOptions()
options.load_capabilities(desired_capabilities)
appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723'
driver = webdriver.Remote(appium_server_url, options=options)
```